# how to implement sub select with where condition in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have these tables:

- products
- stores
- produuctProperties

with this structure

```js
[
  "products" :
    {
        "id": 1,
        "orginalName": "146153-0100 ",
        "title": null,
        "stores": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "stock": 100,
                "minOQ": 1,
                "maxOQ": 0              
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "stock": 100,
                "minOQ": 1,
                "maxOQ": 0,

            }
        ],
        "productproperties": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "productId": 1,
                "propertyId": 8,
                "propertyOptionId": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "productId": 1,
                "propertyId": 9,
                "propertyOptionId": 11
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "productId": 1,
                "propertyId": 10,
                "propertyOptionId": 9
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want filter my products by selected options , Suppose the selected options are 11 and 9

how to implement below sql query in Sequelize 5.6 with findAll , where and... :

```
select * from products as p 
inner join stores as sr on sr.productId = p.id 
where (select count(*) from productProperties where propertyOptionId in (11,9) and productId = p.id) >= 2
```

Comment: [Raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using query builder in sequelize is really confusing,
so if you're good with raw sql you could just run them on as below

if Student is you're model
then 
const students = Student.query('Select *  from students');